# Proof with restrictions on mod

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let n be a positive integer. Prove that $1^2 +2^2 +3^2 + ... +(n-1)^2\equiv 0 \pmod n$ if and only if $n\equiv \pm 1 \pmod 6$

So I figured out that $1^2 +2^2 +3^2 + ... +(n-1)^2$ is equivalent to $\frac{(n-1)(n)(2n-1)}{6}$, but I don't see why the only restriction has to be on the $(n-1)$ factor. Why is the $(2n-1)$ factor also not included in the initial restriction?

Answer (score 2):

$n \equiv 1$ indeed implies that $6 \mid (n-1)$; but that doesn't answer the $n \equiv -1$ case. For that, we need to note that for some $k$, $n = 6k - 1$.

Then $(n-1) = 6k - 2$, so $2 \mid (n-1)$; and $(2n-1) = 12k - 3$. So $3 \mid (2n-1)$.

Therefore, $6 \mid (n-1)(2n-1)$.